# How to stop Akka Cluster member gracefully from supervisord

Tags: akka, supervisord, akka-cluster

I run an Akka Cluster (Version 2.5.0) what is controlled by supervisord (http://supervisord.org/). My problem is, when i stop one akka node with `supervisorctl stop my-service` the akka node stops, but does not have enough time to deregister himself from the akka cluster and furthermore the other nodes do not take control over (i.e.) singleton actors.

My supervisor config looks like this:

```
[program:my-service]
command=java -jar -Dconfig.file=application-1.conf -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  my_service.jar
directory=/data/my-service
autorestart=true
autostart=true
user=lm-service
startsecs=3
startretries=3
stopsignal=KILL
stopwaitsecs=10
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=/data/my-service/logs/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile=/data/my-service/logs/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB
```

Do I have to add some shutdown hook in my akka application, or/and do I have to change the `stopsignal` parameter in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stop signal should be `SIGTERM`. `SIGTERM` will trigger the coordinated shutdown system of akka, your cluster node should correctly leave the cluster in this case. See:

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#coordinated-shutdown
- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#leaving

Still, this won't guarantee that the other nodes will take control in time. See this quote from 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-singleton.html:

> Be aware that there is a short time period when there is no active singleton during the hand-over process.